# React Router Dom NavLink and Link not Working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I just cant get my NavLink or Link to work on my Project, the path changes but nothing gets rendered. I have no ideia what is going on!

Here is the main Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from "react-redux"
import App from './App';
import store from "./redux/store"
import './index.css'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

App.js where I have my main routes that rotate between HOME component and a LOGIN component, in the end I use a catch all.

```
import './App.css';
import { Switch, Route, withRouter } from "react-router-dom"
import Home from './components/Home'
import Login from './components/Login'
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="overall-container">
      <Header/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/home' component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path='/Login' component={Login}/>
        <Route component={Login}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Home.js where I have my switch and the routes

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="homeContainer">
        <h1>TITLE</h1>
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact path= '/home/admin'
            render={() => (
              <CreateDay
                user={this.props.user}
                users={this.props.users}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            exact path= '/home/profile'
            render={() => (
              <Profile
                user={this.props.user}
                users={this.props.users}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route
            exact path= '/home/'
            render={() => (
              <Schedule
                user={this.props.user}
                users={this.props.users}
                teeTimes={this.props.teeTimes}
              />
            )}
          />
          </Switch>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

and finally the Header where I have onn my NavLinks that are not working at all

```
render() {
    return(
      <div className='headerContainer'>
        <NavLink to="/home">
          <img src={home} alt='logo' className='homeButton'/>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/home/profile">
          <div className='profileHeaderContainer'>
              {this.props.user.url ?
                <img src={this.props.user.url} alt='logo' className='userImage'/>
                :
                <img src={userImage} alt='logo' className='userImage'/>
              }
            <div>
              <div className='profileHeaderName'>{this.props.user.userName} {this.props.user.lastName}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </NavLink>
        <img src={sair} alt='logo' className='sair' onClick={this.onSignOut}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Specifying the `exact` prop on the root routes necessarily precludes them from matching any sub-routes.

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path='/home' component={Home}/> // <-- only "/home" exactly
  <Route exact path='/Login' component={Login}/> // <-- only "/Login" exactly
  <Route component={Login}/>
</Switch>
```

## Solution

Remove the `exact` prop so nested switches can match and render routes.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='/home' component={Home}/>
  <Route path='/Login' component={Login}/>
  <Route component={Login}/>
</Switch>
```

You similarly don't need all the `exact` props on the nested routes. In fact, you generally don't, or won't, need to use the `exact` prop at all if you order your routes correctly in decreasing specificity so more specific paths are listed before less specific paths.

Comment: That is just perfect. It partially solved the problem, but now I cannot get my component Schedule on route /home to render.

```
<Route
            exact path= '/home/'
            render={() => (
              <Schedule
                user={this.props.user}
                users={this.props.users}
                teeTimes={this.props.teeTimes}
              />
            )}
          />
```

Comment: @R.Gama remove the `exact` prop and delete the trailing "/" so the path is *just* "/home".